# how to reference other properties into log4j2 yaml configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm using the following log4j2.yaml configuration:

```
Configuration:
 Appenders:
    Console:
      name: Console
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      JSONLayout:
        compact: true
        eventEol: true
        properties: true
        stacktraceAsString: true
        includeTimeMillis: true
        KeyValuePair:
          - key: appName
            value: ${spring.application.name} 
          - key: version
            value: ${spring.application.version} 
          
 Loggers:
    Root:
      level: INFO
      AppenderRef:
        ref: Console
    Logger:
      - name: org.apache
        level: WARN
        AppenderRef:
          ref: Console
      - name: org.springframework.beans.factory
        level: WARN
        AppenderRef:
          ref: Console
```

but on log,

```
{"instant":{"epochSecond":1705250772,"nanoOfSecond":209226000},"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.hyperbank.architecture.base.AbstractHyperBankApplication","message":"Hello, it's me, 'config-provider' !!!","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5,"appName":"${spring.application.name}","version":"${spring.application.version}"}
```

the properties appName and version are not replaced by real value

the same reference is on the banner.txt, and it is correctly displayed.

```
  _  _                    ___            _      ___           __ _        ___             _    _         
 | || |_  _ _ __  ___ _ _| _ ) __ _ _ _ | |__  / __|___ _ _  / _(_)__ _  | _ \_ _ _____ _(_)__| |___ _ _ 
 | __ | || | '_ \/ -_) '_| _ \/ _` | ' \| / / | (__/ _ \ ' \|  _| / _` | |  _/ '_/ _ \ V / / _` / -_) '_|
 |_||_|\_, | .__/\___|_| |___/\__,_|_||_|_\_\  \___\___/_||_|_| |_\__, | |_| |_| \___/\_/|_\__,_\___|_|  
       |__/|_|                                                    |___/                                  

Name: config-provider 
Version: 1.0.0
Powered by Spring Boot 3.1.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Spring Boot Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#spring-boot-lookup) :

```yaml
Configuration:
 Appenders:
    Console:
      name: Console
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      JSONLayout:
        compact: true
        eventEol: true
        properties: true
        stacktraceAsString: true
        includeTimeMillis: true
        KeyValuePair:
          - key: appName
            value: ${spring:spring.application.name} 
          - key: version
            value: ${spring:spring.application.version}
```

and rename the log4j2.yaml into log4j2-spring.yaml